# DropDownList does not set Selected Value from Model

Tags: .net, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to make the edit part of a form. The object I pass to the view is correct. I pass it through this function:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Progetto Progetti = db.Progetti.Find(id);
        if (Progetti == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

//HERE I INITIALIZE TWO LISTS. (One that gets the data from Utenti and the other from Ruoli.)

```
ViewBag.Utenti = new SelectList(db.Utenti.toList(),"IDUTENTE","USERNAME");
        ViewBag.Ruoli = new SelectList(db.Ruoli.ToList(), "id_ruolo", "desc_ruolo");
        return View("index", Progetti); //the object Progetti comes OK
    }
```

In my view I have this :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
        var item = Model.ElementAt(i);
        var index = "rp" + i;
        <input type="hidden" name="progetto.ruoloprogetto[@index].id_ruolo_prog" value="@item.id_ruolo_prog" />
        <tr class="@i" id="@item.id_ruolo_prog">
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="progetto.ruoloprogetto.Index" value="@index" />

                @Html.DropDownListFor(p=> item.id_utente, ViewBag.Utenti as SelectList,
                new
            {
                @Class = "form-control",
                @Name = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "].id_utente",
                @Id = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "]_id_utente"
            })


            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => item.id_ruolo, ViewBag.Ruoli as SelectList,
            new
            {
                @Class = "form-control",
                @Name = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "].id_ruolo",
                @Id = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "]_id_ruolo"
            })

            </td>
```

But the dropdowns get all the list values and do not set the selected value to item.id_utente which is the value I want it to have

Can someone please help with this fast?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Unfortunately @Html.DropDownListFor() behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop so you need to use an `EditorTemplate`. But you should never be rendering controls that way. I assume you must be trying to use a partial and that is the view you have shown. Please post your models and the main view.

Comment: And are you dynamically deleting items from the collection using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way,

```c#
@Html.DropdownListFor(x => x[i].id_ruolo, ViewBag.Ruoli as SelectList,
           new {
                   @Class = "form-control"
               });
```